# stop kafka consumer from consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any way to stop kafka consumers from consuming messages for sometime ?
I want consumer to stop for sometime and later start consuming messages from the last unconsumed message.

Comment: You tagged this aws-msk. Are you trying to achieve this by somehow sending control commands to the brokers or the AWS API, without being in control of the consumers?

Comment: No . We are using kafka APIs to send commands to brokers

Answer (score 0):

Most Kafka libraries have close or pause methods on the Consumer implementation. Or, you could throw some fatal exception during consumption.

Resuming from the last uncommitted offset for a consumer group is the default behavior